# count the combination of items in synchronized lists (as tuples in a dictionary)

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
l1 = ['k', 'l', 'k', 's', 'l', 't', 'k']
l2 = ['h', 't', 'h', 't', 't', 's', 's']
```

I want to count the occurance of combinations of items in the ith position in the first list with the same position in the second lists. I would like the outcome to be:

k-h = 2, l-t = 2, s-t = 1, t-s = 1, k-s = 1

I thought it would be best to first make a tuple out of the lists:

```
tupleList = zip(l1,l2)
tupeleList = [('k', 'h'), ('l', 't'), ('k', 'h'), ('s', 't'), ('l', 't'), ('t', 's'), ('k', 's')]
```

Then make a dictionary to count the unique elements in that list of tuples:

```
myDict = {}
for item in tupleList:
    if item[1] in myDict:
        myDi [ item[1] ] += item[2]
    else
        myDi [ item[1] ] = item[2]
```

but I get this error: 'tuple index out of range'. What is the problem?
Is it perhaps not efficient to first make a tuple?

Comment: Tuples, like lists, in Python start their indexing at zero.

Comment: of course, my mistake - but it doesn´t work since the outcome of that is {'a': 'ccct', 'c': 'g', 't': 'gg', 'g': 'c'}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [7]: import collections
In [10]: count = collections.Counter(zip(l1,l2))

In [11]: count
Out[11]: Counter({('l', 't'): 2, ('k', 'h'): 2, ('s', 't'): 1, ('t', 's'): 1, ('k', 's'): 1})
```

The `collection.Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. So you can generally use it as you would a `dict`, plus have access to some [additional methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) such as `elements`, `most_common`, and `subtract`.

---

If you wanted to fix-up your posted code (with minimal changes), it would look like:

```
l1 = ['k', 'l', 'k', 's', 'l', 't', 'k']
l2 = ['h', 't', 'h', 't', 't', 's', 's']
tupleList = zip(l1,l2)
myDict = {}
for item in tupleList:
    if item in myDict:
        myDict[ item ] += 1
    else:
        myDict[ item ] = 1
print(myDict)
```

---

However, `dict`s have a [get](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method which can be used to simplify your code further:

```
for item in tupleList:
    myDict[item] = myDict.get(item, 0) + 1
```

---

Or, as @JonClements points out in the comments, you could use a 
[collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
myDict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in tupleList:
    myDict[item] += 1
```

Comment: when I try this I get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'. I did import collections and that worked.

Comment: @edg: The `collections.Counter` was introduced in Python2.7. If you are using an older version of Python, you could either use the `setdefault` method, or copy the `Counter` class from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/). That version will work with Python version 2.5 or later.